# Is it possible to save a chart as an image from the Visualizer Plugin

Tags: plugins

**Is it possible to save a chart as an image from the Visualizer Plugin?** (https://sv.wordpress.org/plugins/visualizer/) The author of the plugin writes that it's used with html5/svg, but I can't find any such object in the code so I really don't understand how it is done. Probably magic ;-)

I thought it was html canvas, but when looking at source I only see ordinary divs created, but in the html source there are no content. I'm really not sure where to begin... ): I just want some pointers... How should I grab the chart as an image? I would like to use `toDataURL` on an canvas element or such...

Answer (score 0):

SVGs are images, it stands for [Scalable Vector Graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). You can rightclick on the rendered chart and save it as an image in your browser just as you would do with any normal image.

If you are looking to capture the chart at various points throughout the day you might want to look at the `toHtml()` function in the render class and filter it from there. I would need to have a look at the render classes at home in order to advise better if it is the programmatic route you are taking.